# How to make on certain pages sticky contact form?

Tags: jquery, css

On the webpage is contact form 7, I need to make it fixed to the right side. When the page is open the form is hidden, only form button (open) is visible. On click the form should opens.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your element:

```
<div onClick="myFunction()" id="myForm">open</div>
```

style:

```
<style>
    #myForm{
        background: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        right: -120px;
        cursor: hand;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
var open;
function myFunction(){
    if(open){
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.right='0px';
        document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = 'close';
        open=false;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.right='-120px';
        document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = 'open';
    open=true;
    }
}
</script>
```